# Combining CSS selectors with multiple page id's

Tags: html, css

How can I combine:

```
#page1 .mainmenu {
    padding: 20px; 
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
}
```

with

```
#page2 .mainmenu {
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
}
```

I need to specify around 9 pages or so that all share the `.mainmenu` class. I'm using jQuery mobile and it doesn't work without the #page1/2/3/4 etc selector.

I appreciate this is a basic question but I just can't find the answer.

Comment: just use `.mainmenu {}` and it should work for all pages regardless the `id`

Comment: Wow, this is almost too simple to ask out loud. This is basic CSS and very easy to find

Comment: Condescension is childish at best. FYI what you don't know will also fill the world's largest library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `,` between `#page1 .mainmenu` and `#page2 .mainmenu`.

Like this.

```
#page2 .mainmenu, #page1 .mainmenu {
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
}
```

or

```
.mainmenu {
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
}
```

Will select all with the class `.mainmenu` regardless of the page `id`.